# clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can Any one Tell me how to solve this Error...
My X-Code is Version 4.2.
My IOS Simulator is Version 5.0

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/M3DFree.app/M3DFree normal i386
cd "/Users/savvy3/Desktop/Ayaz/Hemant Sir/PlayScreen-M3D_V2-41d4396ba6d1c8687eb2b744a700649849583714/match3D"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk "-L/Users/savvy3/Desktop/Ayaz/Hemant Sir/PlayScreen-M3D_V2-41d4396ba6d1c8687eb2b744a700649849583714/match3D/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/savvy3/Desktop/Ayaz/Hemant Sir/PlayScreen-M3D_V2-41d4396ba6d1c8687eb2b744a700649849583714/match3D/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/savvy3/Desktop/Ayaz/Hemant Sir/PlayScreen-M3D_V2-41d4396ba6d1c8687eb2b744a700649849583714/match3D/build/Match3D.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Match3DFree.build/Objects-normal/i386/M3DFree.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 AppController.m -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30200 -framework GameKit -lsqlite3.0 -framework StoreKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -o "/Users/savvy3/Desktop/Ayaz/Hemant Sir/PlayScreen-M3D_V2-41d4396ba6d1c8687eb2b744a700649849583714/match3D/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/M3DFree.app/M3DFree"

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The error mentions something about

D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30200

Which is a reference to iOS 3.2 (the first iPad OS). Check your build target and make sure that you are building for iOS 5 and that the deployment target is 4.3 or above.

If that doesn't help then it's probably just "one of those Xcode bugs" and doing a clean build, resetting your simulator, clearing your project cache and rebooting your Mac will probably fix it.

Comment: Thnx for your Replay. is their any other Solution It's not working.

Comment: i am getting much like this error : D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000

Comment: That means the same, but in your case it's saying it's set to iOS 4.0.